# MongoDB find query: return duplicate records but which has unique existing ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection document say test:

```
{id: 123,
 lId: abc,
 cnum: [{num: 112, type:R}]
},
{id: 234,
 lId: abc,
 cnum:[{ num: 112, type: R}]
},
{id: 345,
 lId: cbd,
 cnum: [{num: 112, type: R}]
},
{id: 456,
 lId: efg,
 cnum: [{num: 121, type:R}]
}
```

I want the query to return values with duplicate cnum's num value but unique lId. That is it should return

```
id: 123,lId: abc, cnum.num: 112, id: 345,lId: cbd, cnum.num: 112
```

but currently it is returning

```
id: 123,lId: abc,cnum.num: 112, id: 234, lId: abc, cnum.num: 112, id: 345,lId: cbd, cnum.num: 112
```

My current script is returning the duplicate lId too. Here is my script:

```
var groupCnum = db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{ $match: {"cnum.0": {$exists: true}}},
{ $unwind: "$cnum" },
{ $match: { "cnum.type": "R" } },
{ $group: { "_id": "$cnum.num", "count": { $sum: 1 } } },
{ $match: {"count": {"$gt": 1} } }
], {allowDiskUse: true}).map(record => record._id);

var duplicatedCnum = db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{ $match: {"lId": {$nin: groupCnum}}},
{ $match: { "cnum.num": {$in: groupCnum} } },
{ $unwind: "$cnum" },
{ $match: { "cnum.type": "R" } },
{ $sort: {cnum: 1} },
{ $limit: 100}
], {allowDiskUse: true});
var fieldNames = ["id", "lId", "cnum.num"];
print(fieldNames.join(","));
```

Can anyone suggest what am I missing?

Comment: You have a miss-match in the types from the sample documents you provided and the queries you're using, for example from the queries `cnum` seems to be an array. also how you're getting those return types from this aggregation is beyond me as you're not grouping the `ltd` field so i'm not really sure what's going on. if you could clear things up

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Yes the cnum is an array, sorry for the confusion, I have updated the sample document. I am not getting the return values as above, it is just a sample of the values getting returned. I have updated that too for clarity. Also I am not sure how to group by ```lId``` first and then by ```cnum```. Probably that's what I am not able to get correctly.

Comment: Also can you explain why you don't want all the documents to return? it seems like they all match your requirement

Comment: @TomSlabbaert My requirement is to get the duplicate ```cnum``` values which has distinct ```lId```. So basically if 2 unique ```lId``` share the same ```cnum```.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$cnum"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$cnum.num",
            lId: {$addToSet: "$lId"},
            doc: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "lId.0": {$exists: true}
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$doc"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$doc"
        }
    }
]);
```

Note that for this input:

```
{id: 123, lId: abc, cnum: [{num: 112, type:R}, {num: 224, type: R}]}
{id: 124, lId: cdb, cnum: [{num: 112, type:R}]}
{id: 125, lId: xyz, cnum: [{num: 224, type:R}]}
```

You'll receive this output:

```
{id: 123, lId: abc, cnum: {num: 112, type:R}}
{id: 123, lId: abc, cnum: {num: 224, type:R}}

{id: 124, lId: cdb, cnum: {num: 112, type:R}}
{id: 125, lId: xyz, cnum: {num: 224, type:R}}
```

So if you want to group `abc` again you should add it to `$group` again at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired result with the following query in case it helps someone:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
 {$match: {"cnum.0": { $exists: true }} },
 {$unwind: "$cnum"},
 {$match: { "cnum.type": "R"}},
 {$group: {"_id": {"lId": "$lId", "cnum": "$cnum.num" } } },
 {$group: {"_id": "$_id.cnum", "count": {$sum: 1}}},
 {$match: {"count": {"$gt": 1}}
}])
```